# I'm trying to use font awesome icon in css pseudo element but it's not working what is wrong with my code?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

```html
<html>
<head>

  <style>
h1::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f5fc";
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

is there anything wrong in this code ??
I have changed font weight several times but it keeps on showing that hollow box

Comment: Try to use font awesome version 4. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: create your first kit and paste it to the header tag.

https://fontawesome.com/start

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by importing the Font Awesome CDN link in your `<head>`. These ones oddly don't work.

```html
<head>
<!-- Doesn't work -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

Using the Font Awesome [Webfont with CDN](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/customizing-wordpress/snippets/setup-cdn-webfont) solves the issue.

Check the snippet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    h1::after {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f5fc";
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
h1 {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
}

h1::after {
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        content: "\f5fc";
        position: absolute;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        left: 0;
        top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>Heading</h1>
```

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: Now why you gotta steal my solution

Comment: It works, I've added the fontwsome link.

Comment: Right, cause you copied the link relation I added to the head in my answer... Also, confused as to your positioning, he is using an `::after` to display the icon after the `<h1>` so why position it before the `<h1>`?? I think he just would have used `::before` if that's what he wanted.

Comment: I'm not stealing and I'm not copying anything. I've been a senior frontender for 22 years and your question is very basic.